# How can i monitor FPS in native linux games

Tags: games, framerate

So getting to the question what is the most user friendly overlay option for measuring native linux games framerate (preferably no compiling necessary)?

I have done a fair amount of research and i understand that there are a few methods to choose from. The available solutions i have looked at include Frapix, fluffy tapeworm, BuGLE, and mumble. I have only found moderate success with the last option (mumble) i can start a program with the mumble-overlay command after navigating to the proper folder. And as far as i can tell everything is up and running fine however when i launch rust.x86 it fails to get past the grey screen with facepunch logo(I can see the frame rate overlay). So i am left only with programs that need to be compiled. And while i am not computer illiterate i am not proficient enough with linux to compile a program(not for a lack of trying).

(game in question Rust by Facepunch hosted on steam for linux which runs fine without the overlay) 
The game does not have an internally programmed frame monitor and is natively run so wine and play on linux tips and tricks will not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use steam you can enable this option in the steam overlay settings and it should work with any game that works with the steam overlay.  It lets you choose what corner of the screen you want the counter to be in and I recommend using the high contrast color setting so that you can easily see the fps counter at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run Steam, configure its overlay to show the FPS counter and load it into your application by running it with the following environment variable applied:

`LD_PRELOAD="$HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so:$HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so" ./game`